# Heroku does not validate certificate requests, why?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails server running in Heroku and I've been trying to add SSL for communicate with app clients, developed with Android, for while.

I created a [self-signed certificate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self) as explained on Heroku's site and added end-point as [this Heroku's tutorial suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint). Everything seems perfect, I tested the certificate and it worked too. To force the server to redirect to https protocol, I added 'rack-ssl-enforcer' gem too.

The problem is, when hitting any server route using no certificate in header/payload, (REST Console or curl), I imagined the ruby server should deny the request, allowing only when requests have the valid certificate. However, it is returning the same value as when there was no SSL protocol in the project.

Do I have to configure anything more? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the relevant middleware config as described [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2010/11/29/ssl-with-rails/)?

```
# config/environments/production.rb
require 'rack/ssl'
config.middleware.use Rack::SSL
```

Comment: The "require 'rack/ssl'" worked, but "config.middleware.use Rack::SSL" doesn't work because with rack-ssl-enforce I've to use "config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer". In Heroku stills the same problem, but running "rails s -e production" the browser raises: "SSL connection error Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have." I tried: curl --cert server.crt "https://localhost:3000" and I received: unable to set private key file: 'server.crt' type PEM. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails > 3.2 you can set this config

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

No need for an additional Gem or Rack middleware.

Comment: Nice. But why running `curl -v https://www.example.com` I still getting the page when I should receive a forbidden or bad request?

Comment: Why you should receive a forbidden? You forced https and you're getting https://www.example.com, it's fine.

Comment: But, this way anyone could get or send server data. I would like to offer some routes just for Android app client. For example, I have a route which is responsible for listing in a json, all cities in a country: `https://example.com/cities/brazil`. Today, anyone who runs `curl -v https://example.com/cities/brazil` could fetch all brazilian cities, having the certificate or not. That's the problem. I imagine that only requests passing the right certificate could retrieve the cities. How could I fix this?